# c shell script: find the directory and rename it

Tags: shell, find, rename

i am still new in this shell script. I have  a task that given to me which i have difficulty to execute it.
The task is i have a lot of directory which is based on ddmmyy.

```
03Mar2014  08Aug2013  11Jan2015  16Jan2014  22Feb2014  26Mar2014  
03Nov2013  08Jan2014  11Jul2013  16Jul2013  22Jul2013  26Oct2014  
03Oct2013  08Jan2015  11Nov2014  16May2014  22Mar2014  26Sep2013
```

The task is to make the directory to mmyy.

So far, my code is

```
foreach file(`find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'`) 
echo $file
set newmove = `echo $file | cut -c 1-2,5-`
echo $newmove
mv $file $newmove

output:
for find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3':
./24Jan2015/W51A
`echo $file | cut -c 1-2,5-`
./Jan2015/W51A
mv $file $newmove
mv: cannot rename ./24Jan2015/W51A to   ./Jan2015/W51A: No such file or directory
```

but the script didnt work. 
Do you guys have any idea how to do this?

Comment: `sh` and especially `bash` are much better alternatives than `csh`.  This is a bit over-the-top, but its technical points are accurate:  http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Answer (score 0):

First note: your example shows files in the `ddmmyy` format (in the same dir), not `dd/mm/yy`. If it's indeed so your `find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'` won't find them, thus `foreach` would complain due to empty arg list:

```
> foreach ( '' )
foreach: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

Second note: assuming you find the files your `cut` statement doesn't quite get the proper corresponding destination dir (regardless which of `ddmmyy` or `dd/mm/yy` is the correct filename format):

```
> echo '08Aug2013' | cut -c 1-2,5-
08g2013
> echo '08/Aug/2013' | cut -c 1-2,5-
08ug/2013
```

Your `echo` statements should have pointed out that your script is not doing the expected job.

Trying each piece of the code by itself to make sure it does what's expected of it is usually a good starting point in debugging scripts. Start from the beginning, with `find . -type d`. Comment out the `move` statement until the `echo` statements show correct/expected script operation.